# Setting to zero of elements of a numpy array different from a value (python3) : a[a <> 5] = 0

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

In python 2, the following code works:

```
a = np.array([[1,5],[2,3]])
print a
print()
a[a<2] = 0
print a
a[a <> 5] = 0
print a
```

But in python3, it triggers a syntax error:

```
a[a <> 5] = 0

File "<ipython-input-14-165e29d9f8e4>", line 1
    a[a <> 5] = 0
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for "not equal to" is now `a[a != 5] = 0`

(Yet another instance of a backward compatibility break in Python 3).

Comment: I don't ever recall using `<>` in Py2.  I expect languages to accept one of these instead `!=` or `~=`.

Comment: `<>` is endemic in the BASIC world.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `<>` was replaced by `!=`. It is similar to how `print` was changed from a statement to a function. See [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) in the Docs:

> `!=` can also be written `<>`, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use `!=`.

P.s: You can be quite sneaky and do:

```
from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL
```

which allows `<>` and makes `!=` a SyntaxError, but really don't, just use `!=`.

Comment: The warning about `<>` being an obsolete spelling goes back to 2.0 or earlier.